# How to fix a not refreshed GrailsWebApplicationContext?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm upgrading my project from java 6 to java 8 and grails 2.1.3 to grails 2.3.9 and during the process I had to update some dependencies as well.
Now when I try to run grails run-app I'm getting this error but I don't know exactly where to look for to solve this one.

```
| Error 2016-05-03 14:39:10,507 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext@79418b69 has not been refreshed yet
Message: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext@79418b69 has not been refreshed yet
    Line | Method
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

Did someone face an error like this one? Or if you have some direction about what can I look for to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like this is an end result of something else that went wrong earlier in the startup process. Is there any other errors before that?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a dependency problem on two different versions of spring or some other underlying frame work. See here:  https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/#!msg/vcap-dev/ixuMoCT2tlM/aLtEdZhRPTEJ